# Trying to use extern in reverse order

Tags: c++, c, static-linking, extern

When we have an `exe` or `dll` and a `static library` attached to it, we are able to use `extern` keyword to access static library's `variables` and/or `functions` from the `exe` or `dll`. To make things simpler, let's assume ve have an `exe` and a `lib` attached to it.

What I am trying to do is to call a function of `exe` from `lib`.

Executable Code

```
void doSomething() {
    // do something here
}
```

Static Linked Library Code

```
void onSomeEvent() {
    doSomething(); // call doSomething() here
}
```

Vice versa is easy but I wonder if this can be done in a way like `extern` keyword. Or what is the best method?

What comes to my mind is to pass a `function pointer` (like `void*`) to one of the `functions` / `methods` in the `lib` (probably to a class constructor). I think this should work but I don't want to touch library's code too much since library is not mine and can be replaced with newer versions. I can add/remove a few lines of code to it but I want to prevent from changing function interfaces.

What is the **better** way?

Comment: This is highly platform specific. What compiler/toolchain do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you merely have to declare the function in the library.

```
void onSomeEvent() {
    void doSomething(); // declares the function
    doSomething(); // call doSomething() here
}
```

Comment: strangely worked very well. :) i know what prototype is but i just met its usage like this one. thanks so much dude.

Answer (score 4):

You may also declare it outside your function, you may have other functions need it.

```
void doSomething(); // declares the function

void onSomeEvent() 
{
    doSomething(); // call doSomething() here
}

void onSomeEvent2() 
{
    doSomething(); // call doSomething() here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the static library is (probably) meant to be used in many different programs, it's not uncommon to use the callback approach where the exe initialises the library and passes it one or more function pointers to use to do things (like logging messages, or whatever).  If the exe doesn't pass in the function pointers (or passes them as `NULL`) then the library can simply not call those functions and the library will work well in both environments.

This is *much* better than assuming the functions are always defined in the exe.

Comment: thank you for your comment but in my case, avakar's answer is exactly what i was looking for. though you are right about you points.